# I'm Coding A Naughts and Crosses Game

Tags: python, function

For a School Project i am coding a naughts and crosses game. I am trying to create it in a way that an existing tile cannot be overwritten, but my code does not seem to be working and i cannot find the solution to fix it.
Below is the code:

```
import random 

y = 0 
Tic_Tac = ['null','null','null', 
           'null','null','null', 
           'null','null','null' 
           ] 

def basic_computer_UI(Tic_Tac_Toe_list,list_of_taken_numbers): 
    x = 1 
    while x == 1: 
        place_tic_tac = random.randint(0,8) 
        if place_tic_tac not in list_of_taken_numbers: 
            Tic_Tac_Toe_list[place_tic_tac] = 'o' 
            list_of_taken_numbers.append(str(place_tic_tac)) 
            print(Tic_Tac_Toe_list) 
            x = 0 
        else: 
            x = 1 

while y == 0: 
    change_var = input("enter the number you want to change") 
    change_var_int = int(change_var) 
    list_change = [] 
    if change_var not in list_change: 
        list_change.append(change_var) 
        Tic_Tac[change_var_int - 1] = 'x' 
        print('\n',Tic_Tac[0],'\t',Tic_Tac[1],'\t',Tic_Tac[2],'\n', 
                   Tic_Tac[3],'\t',Tic_Tac[4],'\t',Tic_Tac[5],'\n', 
                   Tic_Tac[6],'\t',Tic_Tac[7],'\t',Tic_Tac[8]) 
        basic_computer_UI(Tic_Tac,list_change) 
    else: 
        print("you cannot overwrite a pre-existing number")
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Why are you using string `'null'` as a placeholder? Why not `None`? It's also time to learn about loops so you can print out multiple lines with one line of code and an iterator variable.

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't describe your problem in sufficient detail for anyone to help you

Comment: I mean, i really carnt explain it any better. If the user tries to place an 'x' in a space that has allready been taken, it doesnt seem to work. It should check if the number they are trying to enter is in list_change, and if not enter it. If it is it should tell them that its not possible.

Comment: Also, to the other person having a go at me for using 'null' I ask what is the advantage to using None. And I realise i could have used for n in range(8) and used that to print them out, but i was in a hurry and found this faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resetting list_change to [] on every iteration. 
Try moving it up to where you define your other global variables.